# What identity of derivative is applied to the following equation?

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives, probability-distributions

As I read through this [Pyro tutorial](https://pyro.ai/examples/svi_part_iii.html), I found out the following equation:

$$\nabla_{\phi} q_{\phi}(z) = q_{\phi}(z) \nabla_{\phi} \log q_{\phi}(z)$$

where $q_{\phi}(z)$ is a distribution of the random variable z with parameter $\phi$.

I am wondering what identity of derivative is applied here to prove it is true?

Any help or reference link is appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn’t that be because the derivative of the logarithm is $(\nabla _{\phi} q_{\phi}(z))/q_{\phi}(z))$?

Comment: @FedePoncioThank you very much for the help. I think you are correct. To be more precise, I think it should be ln instead of log.